# My links are visually breaking as soon as screen is resized

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I'm creating my own links manually within a module of a divi theme, since divi doesn't support three links side by side.

It's supposed to look like this:

[Three side-by-side links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ5iM.png)

But when the screen is resized it looks like this: [Split looking link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNPZF.png)

Divi breaks its responsive at certain points and this happens before it gets to the tablet size.

This is the code I've placed in the module's css:

```css
a.work {
  background-color: #b7ad68;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-family: "helvetica", san-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
}

a:hover.work {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #b7ad68;
  color: #b7ad68;
}

a.podcast {
  background-color: #f1b36e;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-family: "helvetica", san-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
}

a:hover.podcast {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #f1b36e;
  color: #f1b36e;
}

a.speak {
  background-color: #e58059;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-family: "helvetica", san-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
}

a:hover.speak {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #e58059;
  color: #e58059;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="work" href="/work-with-me">
    <span style="font-family: ETmodules; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 300; padding-top: 10px; position: relative; top: .15em;">&#xe0ef;</span>&nbsp;WORK WITH ME</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="podcast" href="/work-with-me"><span style="font-family: ETmodules; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 300; position: relative; top: .15em;">&#xe01b;</span>&nbsp;PODCAST</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a
    class="speak"><span style="font-family: ETmodules; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 300;position: relative; top: .15em;">&#xe031;</span>&nbsp;SPEAKING</a>
</p>
```

Comment: You need to post the complete relevant code, i.e. also the HTML of that part of the page

Comment: Maybe just add `white-space: pre`, to forbid those elements from breaking at "opportunities" such as spacing between words ...?

Comment: @Johannes Good to know, I'll be sure to do that next time

Answer (score 0):

These links contain `<span>` elements, which are inline by default (same as the `<a>` tag itself), and therefore will break like regular text. To avoid that, you can define either the spans or those links as `inline-block`s, then they won't be split/broken like regular text. For this, add the following rule:

```
a.work,
a.podcast,
a.speak {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
a.work,
a.podcast,
a.speak {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.work {
  background-color: #b7ad68;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-family: "helvetica", san-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
}

a:hover.work {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #b7ad68;
  color: #b7ad68;
}

a.podcast {
  background-color: #f1b36e;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-family: "helvetica", san-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
}

a:hover.podcast {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #f1b36e;
  color: #f1b36e;
}

a.speak {
  background-color: #e58059;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-family: "helvetica", san-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
}

a:hover.speak {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #e58059;
  color: #e58059;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="work" href="/work-with-me">
    <span style="font-family: ETmodules; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 300; padding-top: 10px; position: relative; top: .15em;">&#xe0ef;</span>&nbsp;WORK WITH ME</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="podcast" href="/work-with-me"><span style="font-family: ETmodules; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 300; position: relative; top: .15em;">&#xe01b;</span>&nbsp;PODCAST</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a
    class="speak"><span style="font-family: ETmodules; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 300;position: relative; top: .15em;">&#xe031;</span>&nbsp;SPEAKING</a>
</p>
```